# Python: Convert hex to string

Tags: python, string, hex

A value like `0x0F` or `0x05` has to be given to a function as a string without the 0x at the beginning so `0F` or `05`.

If I use `str(hex(0x0F))[2:4]` I only get `f`. It is crucial that the missing `0` is still present in my application.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.format):

```
In [1]: '{:02X}'.format(0x0F)
Out[1]: '0F'
```

In this context `{:02X}` is equivalent to `{0:02X}`. Preceding the colon with *0* tells Python to apply this to the first argument of `str.format` (*0x0F* in this example). *02* sets the minimum field width to *2* and

> Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware
>   zero-padding for numeric types

*X* is one of the available integer presentation types:

> Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using upper- case letters
>   for the digits above 9.

Both quotes are from [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: What means In[14] and Out[14]?

Comment: @Creatronik this is what [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell adds. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Ok, this works fine, but can you give me a link, where this whole {:02X} statement is explained more in detail? Or maybe do it yourself right away :D